# How should horizontal dashboard numbers react on a responsive page?

Tags: layout, numbers, header, fixed-header

I have a set of dashboard values on a sticky horizontal panel on the top of the UI. These numbers are sales values so they are pretty important to the user.

The layout looks something like this:

[image]

But, as you can imagine, on screens with a smaller width, the numbers start overflowing on the sides.

**What would you suggest as being the best solution for presenting these numbers on smaller desktop screens**, given that the top panel shouldn't change shape, so it doesn't cover any more real-estate on the page bellow?

Comment: The height will not change so you are asking how to implement it on a horizontal overflow or also consider displaying them differently (eg. one over the other) ?

Comment: A note about hiding these "important" numbers...they may be important, but they may also only be *temporarily* important. Once the user's read the daily/hourly/whateverly numbers, I suspect they don't need them on the screen anymore. When screen real-estate is limited, perhaps only showing these numbers under certain conditions is a better strategy than trying to keep them on the screen at all times, but laying them out differently.

Comment: What accuracy is of importance on smaller screens? In your example it's clearly visible, that the smallest amount making the change is $1. But does it matter in practice?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The best way to cover long numbers on small devices is to use the K, M, B values; such as 10K, 10.51M etc...

As per layout try resizing this codepen, you'll get an idea https://codepen.io/geoffyuen/pen/FCBEg

[This page](http://sitesforprofit.com/responsive-table-plugins-and-patterns) has couple of good examples to consider.

Comment: A nice library that does this is d3-format https://github.com/d3/d3-format; for example: d3.format("$,.3s")(7654321)

Comment: Of course, if you have enough numbers that need to be shown, it may be good to turn it into a dropdown that shows the list vertically for small-enough screens instead. You can't have everything displayed all the time on something like a phone.

Comment: Even when there is plenty of space, it can be clearer to present numbers this way.  8 significant figures is much more than necessary in most circumstances; *$10.5 M* is quicker to parse at a glance than *$10,480,114*.

Comment: You're right, thanks for all the help. Great stuff!